# How to check debug logs for trigger when executed from the front end?

Tags: apex, trigger, debug-logs

How can I check the debug logs for my trigger when some goes to my website and clicks a button that inserts records on salesforce?

Comment: is this a guest user interacting with a public Site? Is it an API call from some server into SFDC?  More detail is required.  Debugging is always in the context of the running user (who might be a guest user, or integration user ..but always a sfdc user)

Comment: I just checked, the record is created by System. How can set a trace flag in debug logs when the user is System ?

Comment: please refer to my other question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325715/how-can-i-see-debug-logs-when-the-record-is-created-by-system-as-a-user

Comment: Lol, I am the one who just posted that. There is no answer for that yet.

Comment: That's just a result of flagging this one to be closed - it would have been better to edit this question instead of creating another.