# How can I see debug logs, when the record is created by System as a user?

Tags: apex, debug, debug-logs

[image]

I am trying to setup a trace flag to debug. When I select User in the dropdown and try to find System in there. It doesn't show up.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the help article- [Debug a system user](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333602&type=1&mode=1)

> **The standard "debug logs" page does not allow you to set up a debug
> log for certain users such as the S2S connection users or automated
> users.**
>
> You can use the Tooling API to create a new trace flag (debug log )
> for this type of users.
>
> 1. Log into Workbench https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php
> 2. Navigate to Utilities > REST Explorer
> 3. Select POST, enter the URI below, and use the example body provided
>
> /services/data/v35.0/tooling/sobjects/TraceFlag/
>
> {   "TracedEntityId" : "005i0000002Xx2qAAC", "ExpirationDate" :
> "2016-01-07T15:04:31.000+0000",   "DebugLevelId" :
> "7dli0000000GmaEAAS",   "LogType" : "USER_DEBUG",   "StartDate" :
> "2016-01-07T14:34:31.000+0000"   }

Comment: Trying it out right now.